# Single store vs Multi store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, ecommerce-tracking

We already have a website built using magento 2.0. where in we have an existing product category.Now we have a new requirement where we plan to add a new product type , very different from existing one .For example ticket registration is already in place, where we sell tickets to customers and now we plan to sell tshirts too on the same website.

The main requirement is that the treatment will be different of the two product categories(i,e.ticket and t shirts),
where in we should be able to customize add to cart , order confirmation pages etc. Users would not be split between the categories.We may add other e commerce products too in future like shoes etc..

Pls opine your valuable feedback,on whether we should go for **single store** (treating as a different product category) or a **sub store for each product category** ?

Appreciate your help and time

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Store is meant to treat different language only.
So when you talk about store, I guess you want in fact to talk about website.

On my side I don't see any good reason leading to have one website per category...otherwise you will end up by having 100 websites. You need to create your customization based on specific product types and category.
If your products are that different they will have their own attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, here you have 1 option.

**Multi Website** :

A. create separate website for the categories.

B. Each website give you flexibility to change the template according to requirement without affected other template.

C. Each website give you flexibility to change email template according to requirement.

D. Other things also you can set at different website level.